# How to make a Confirm Dialog Appear before Form Post Request in EJS template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, ejs

I'm trying to create a confirmation dialog using something like this: `confirm('Are you sure?')` inside of my EJS form but I don't know where and how to get it to work correctly.

Here is the code I have so far for my EJS template:

```
<div id="popupAddUser" class="addUser">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7"><h2>Create New User</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" id="formAddUser" action="/add-user" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-5 float-right">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type a User name"
                                       name="create_user">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" form="formAddUser" onclick="checker()">Create
                                    User
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function checker(){
        if( confirm("Are you sure you want to create a new User in the database?")){
            continue;
        }else{
            break;
        }   
    }
</script>
```

I'm aware that the checker() function isn't correctly placed or even necessary but I'm not sure if there's another way to do this. When I click the create user button, the Confirm dialog box should render and ask me if I'm sure I want to create a user. If I select yes, it should submit the form but if I click cancel, it shouldn't do the form post request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript `submit()` function to remotely submit your form depending on the response. This would mean that instead of using a submit button, you'd have to use a normal button.

```js
function checker(){
  if(window.confirm("Are you sure")){
    document.getElementById("formAddUser").submit();
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="popupAddUser" class="addUser">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7"><h2>Create New User</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" id="formAddUser" action="/add-user" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-5 float-right">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type a User name"
                                       name="create_user">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" form="formAddUser" onclick="checker()">Create
                                    User
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the button type is set to `button` rather than `submit` to prevent the page from refreshing after the function runs.

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver :) I had no idea that I needed to set the button type to button rather than submit

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised your text editor did not complain about the continue and break statement in your if-else statement!!
I would:

- Remove the inline onclick event handler
- Use instead the addEventListener() method or the onsubmit call on the form element.
- Use event.preventDefault() method to stop the form from submitting when the cancel button is clicked.

  ```
  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener(
   'submit', 
   (e) => checker(e)
  )

  function checker(e) {
   if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
     e.preventDefault()
     alert('Form was not submitted')
   }else {
     alert('New user created')
   }
  }
  ```